# search function in Fat Free framework through SQL

Tags: php, sql, fat-free-framework

I am trying to make a search function where the user can type to search the database and return any matches.I am having a problem linking the user input into the SQL query.

The problem here is the POST.search is taken as a string and I want it to be the user input.

I have tried this way but $db and $f3 does not get recognised -

```
 $db->exec(
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE search=?',
$f3->get('POST.search')
);
```

This is my code -

In the Model - User.php

```
class User extends DB\SQL\Mapper {

public function __construct(DB\SQL $db) {
    parent::__construct($db,'table');
}

public function searchq() {

$search = ('POST.search');      
$q="Select * table where name LIKE '$search'";
return $this->db->exec($q);
}
}
```

In the user controller:

```
    public function search()
    {


    $user = new User($this->db);
    $this->f3->set('table',$user->searchq($search));        
    $this->f3->set('view','search.htm');

    }
```

How do I get it to work through my way or how can I get the way where $db and $f3 is not recognised to work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a wrong method syntax, see https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/sql#exec

it should be:

```
$db->exec('SELECT * FROM table WHERE search = ?',
  array(1 => $f3->get('POST.search'))
);
```

and for LIKE:

```
$db->exec('SELECT * FROM table WHERE search LIKE ?',
  array(1 => '%'.$f3->get('POST.search').'%')
);
```

Comment: The thing is I get an undefined variable for db and f3. I have used the DB\SQL\Mapper and a public construct. See above I've updated. Maybe I haven't defined the database properly?

Comment: as this was just an example, you need to resolve $db and $f3 yourself of course... looks like you got them at $this->db and $this->f3 ?!?!?????